# Can't curl the response at port 9200，but can ping directly

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have deployed elasticsearch in my remote server at port 9200, and I ran the command:

`curl http://localhost:9200`

it returns the correct response.

But when I use this command locally:

`curl http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:9200` (xxx.xxx.xxx.xx is remote server IP),
it shows connection failed.

but when I am using the command:
`ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xx -p 9200`,it connects successfully

remote: 
`curl http://localhost:9200` (ok)

local:
`curl http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:9200`(failed)
`ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xx -p 9200` (ok)

Comment: Can you share your `elasticsearch.yml` file?

Comment: I have reconfigure the elasticsearch.yml file and it it has been solved

Answer (score 1):

Make sure setting `network.host` is set to a non-loopback address. Set `network.host: 0.0.0.0`

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/network.host.html

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `network.host` in your `elasticsearch.yml` is set to localhost.

You can bind to multiple hosts as said in Documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#network-interface-values. So in your case it could be:

```
network.host
- _local_
- _site_
```

And then you should be able to reach ES from both local network and that machine itself as `localhost`